# Extract from long string

Tags: javascript, string, sharepoint, extract

I am currently using SharePoint however I have a technical question, I am currently using some JQuery to get a video source from a Page that is in a pages library, however this returns the code below:

```
<dl>
  <dt>MediaSource</dt>
  <dd>
    <a href="/Videos/Life Changing/video1.mp4">link</a>
  </dd>
  <dt>PreviewImageSource</dt>
  <dd>
    <a href="/Videos/Life Changing/Preview Images/snapshot.png">link</a>
  </dd>

  <dd>Inline</dd>
  <dt>AutoPlay</dt>
  <dd>False</dd>
  <dt>Loop</dt>
  <dd>False</dd>
  <dt>InlineHeight</dt>
  <dd>360px</dd>
  <dt>InlineWidth</dt>
  <dd>640px</dd>
  <dt>ShowEmbedControl</dt>
  <dd>True</dd>
  <dt>ConfigureFromContext</dt>
  <dd>False</dd>
  <dt>VideoSetSource</dt>
  <dd>
    <a href="/Videos/Life Changing">link</a>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

I need to extract the ".mp4" url and also the ".png" url so that I can use them in an iframe, how would be best to go about this please?

My code in full is:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getVideoNews);
})


function getVideoNews() {
    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists();
    list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Pages');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope=\'Recursive\'><RowLimit>5</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\'Comments\' /><FieldRef Name=\'LikesCount\' /><FieldRef Name=\'FileRef\' /><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' /><FieldRef Name=\'Rich_x0020_Video_x0020_Embed\' /><FieldRef Name=\'Summary_x0020_Text\' /></ViewFields><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ContentType\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>News Video</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Created\' Ascending=\'True\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
    camlQuery.set_folderServerRelativeUrl('News Videos');
    collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(list);
    context.load(collListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, newsvideoSuccessHandler),
     Function.createDelegate(this, newsvideoErrorHandler));
}

function newsvideoSuccessHandler(result) {

    listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        var newsvideotitle = oListItem.get_item("Title");
        var newsvideolink = oListItem.get_item("FileRef");
        var newsvideo = oListItem.get_item("Rich_x0020_Video_x0020_Embed");

    }

}

function newsvideoErrorHandler(sender, args) {
    alert('Camelot News Video Error: \nRequest failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're getting HTML as a string from a rich text field with the following line:

```
var newsvideo = oListItem.get_item("Rich_x0020_Video_x0020_Embed");
```

Rather than manually parsing that HTML string as text, you can transform it into actual HTML elements and then use JavaScript's built-in DOM parsing utilities (or use jQuery) with little fanfare, assuming the number and placement of `<a>` elements is consistent:

```
var newsvideo = oListItem.get_item("Rich_x0020_Video_x0020_Embed");
var dummyElement = document.createElement("div");
dummyElement.innerHTML = newsvideo;
var links = dummyElement.querySelectorAll("a");
var videoUrl = links[0].href;
var imageUrl = links[1].href;
```

Of course, that's inside your `while` loop; if you have multiple records being iterated, you may want to handle the storage of those values differently. The above code is just an example to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested! You can try to find a elements using jQuery and then get the href value ex:

```
$(this).find("a")
```

then get the href value with .attr('href') and you should get a list of all links.

Comment: I probably should have posted my full code, this is not running on an actual page, it is querying a SharePoint library for a video source and this is what it is returning. I will edit my post now.

Comment: I need more info on this. In what variable you get that first code? list var what it contains? In any case I think you get that code as a string or as an array and you need to parse it to get the urls.

Comment: I have updated my question to include my source code, I hope this explains everything better. Sorry!